# No such property: expected for class: Script1343 (in groovy script);

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

I am trying to retrieve data from oracle db but getting  No such property: expected for class: Script1343 (in groovy script);  error

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.InputStream;
import groovy.sql.Sql;

def url = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/TEST'
def user = 'DB'
def password = 'DB'
def driver = 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
def sql = Sql.newInstance('url', 'User',     'password','oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver')
sql.withStatement { 
   stmt -> stmt.queryTimeout = 30
   print "Request TimeOut"
} 

def rowNum = 0
sql.eachRow("SELECT DISTINCT CST_START_DT_PF,CST_ITEM_NUM_PF  FROM COST "){     row ->
  def first = row[0]
  def middle = row.CST_START_DT_PF
  def one = row.CST_ITEM_NUM_PF
  assert expected[rowNum] == "$CST_START_DT_PF, $CST_ITEM_NUM_PF" 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several things wrong.  The specific error you asked about is the result of the following:

```
assert expected[rowNum] == "$CST_START_DT_PF, $CST_ITEM_NUM_PF"
```

You are referencing a variable `expected` which doesn't exist.

You didn't ask about the things below but other problems you are going to run into...

Referencing `$CST_START_DT_PF` and `$CST_ITEM_NUM_PF` is going to be a problem because they also don't exist, at least not in a way that your code will work.

You also are probably going to get unexpected results related to the fact that you are never incrementing `rowNum`.